# How to configure Redhat Developer (pom.xml)

Tags: jboss, pom.xml, redhat

I'm new to Jboss.

I tried everything: the Jboss documentation, YouTube videos, but I'm out of luck.

I'm using Redhat Developer to run quickstart examples like helloworld but I don't know why I am having this POM.xml error. I follow everything but still I'm getting this error.

As you can see the server is running good but I cannot see the option run as server.

I'm using Win 10 and Jboss eap 7.1 for runtime.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyyCJ.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47km.jpg)

[fullimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2qov.jpg)

[progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joymh.jpg)

Comment: can you please try to build the project with `mvn clean install` and see if that works. if yes maybe try a `Maven -> Update Project`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please try to use correct case here, and refrain from "txtspk" ruinations of English. If you are posting on a mobile phone, please find a laptop or desktop machine to post from.

Comment: @halfer sorry sir. I will be more carefull next time. yes im using mobile that time. I am really sorry.

Comment: @wirnse I tried what you said but unfortunately, It didn't work.

Comment: What did not work? Is it failing at `mvn clean install`? Also have a look at [configure-run-on-server-option-on-a-maven-project-on-eclipse-ide](http://consistentcoder.com/configure-run-on-server-option-on-a-maven-project-on-eclipse-ide)

Comment: @wirnse yes it failed too. I tried that run on server but I had many errors. Around 17 errors. I don't know why. I will post the error on my questions.

Comment: It seems you are having problems with the connection. Are you behind a proxy? Try to open the [Redhat Maven repository](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/) in the browser.

Comment: @wirnse I can open it. I am exporting the maven file from quickstart. Every time I tried mvn clean install it there is always an error I don't know why is it.

Comment: @wirnse I made some progress, 1 more error. See the image of progress. It tried to download something but somehow it doesn't allow it. I tried to download it my self then made the appropriate folder and the file, but still doesn't work.